# How to get added values in JSP form out of arraylist using servlet - I get empty Class

Tags: java, arraylist, servlets

I can pass values from JSP using Java Servlet to ReimbersementDao, as I debuged, ArrayList is getting data, but if I want to display it back in table I got empty view. If I add data using hard coding, I can display it. How to add, or delete data that is added in form jsp view and than display it back while ArrayList is populated. I tried to overload the addReimbursementItem() method but I can't get the object from it - it's null.

Hardcode adding works and display values if I set getDefaultValues method in servlet:

```
public List<Reimbursement> getDefaultValues() {
 List<Reimbursement> reimbursementList = new ArrayList<>();
 reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("taxi", 0.3, 1.5));
 reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("hotel", 0.5, 0.5));
 reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("air ticket", 0.2, 1.0));
 reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("train", 1.3, 2.5));
 reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("bus", 0.8, 2.2));
 return reimbursementList;
}
```

But if I am adding values from jsp, though it's populating ArrayList in method: addReimbursementItem(String value, double value1, double value2){} I can't take this values out from it.

AddServlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {

 double rates = 0;
 double allowance = 0;

 String receipts = request.getParameter("receipts");
 String rateString = request.getParameter("rates");
 String allowanceString = request.getParameter("allowance");

 rates = Double.parseDouble(rateString);
 allowance = Double.parseDouble(allowanceString);
 ReimbursementDao reimbursementDao = new ReimbursementDao();
 reimbursementDao.addReimbursementItem(receipts, rates, allowance);
 response.sendRedirect("/adminListServlet");
}
```

I can pass values from JSP using Java Servlet to ReimbersementDao, as I debuged, ArrayList is getting data, but if I want to display it back in table I got empty view. If I add data using hard coding, I can display it. How to add, or delete data that is added in form jsp view and than display it back while ArrayList is populated.

Hardcode adding works and display values:

```
public List<Reimbursement> getDefaultValues() {
List<Reimbursement> reimbursementList = new ArrayList<>();
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("taxi", 0.3, 1.5));
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("hotel", 0.5, 0.5));
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("air ticket", 0.2, 1.0));
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("train", 1.3, 2.5));
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("bus", 0.8, 2.2));
return reimbursementList;
}
```

But if I am adding values from jsp, though it's populating ArrayList in method: addReimbursementItem(String value, double value1, double value2){} I can't take this values out from it.

AddServlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {

double rates = 0;
double allowance = 0;

String receipts = request.getParameter("receipts");
String rateString = request.getParameter("rates");
String allowanceString = request.getParameter("allowance");

rates = Double.parseDouble(rateString);
allowance = Double.parseDouble(allowanceString);
ReimbursementDao reimbursementDao = new ReimbursementDao();
reimbursementDao.addReimbursementItem(receipts, rates, allowance);
response.sendRedirect("/adminListServlet");
}
}
```

ReimbursementDao:

```
public class ReimbursementDao {
private List<Reimbursement> reimbursementList;

public List<Reimbursement> getDefaultValues() {
List<Reimbursement> reimbursementList = new ArrayList<>();
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("taxi", 0.3, 1.5));
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("hotel", 0.5, 0.5));
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("air ticket", 0.2, 1.0));
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("train", 1.3, 2.5));
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement("bus", 0.8, 2.2));
return reimbursementList;
}

public List<Reimbursement> addReimbursementItem(String receipts, double rates, double 
allowance){
List<Reimbursement> reimbursementList = new ArrayList<>();
reimbursementList.add(new Reimbursement(receipts, rates, allowance));
System.out.println(reimbursementList);
return reimbursementList;
}

public List<Reimbursement> addReimbursementItem(){

return reimbursementList;
 }
}
```

ListingServlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "AdminListServlet", value = "/adminListServlet")
public class AdminListServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

ReimbursementDao reimbursementDao = new ReimbursementDao();
List<Reimbursement> reimbursementList = reimbursementDao.addReimbursementItem();
session.setAttribute("reimbursementList", reimbursementList);
if (session.getAttribute("reimbursementList") != null){
    request.setAttribute("reimbursementList", 
session.getAttribute("reimbursementList"));
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/admin.jsp")
            .forward(request, response);
}else{
    response.getWriter().append("No values");
    
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/adminAddServlet").forward(request,response);
}
}
}
```

ReimbursementModel:

```
public class Reimbursement {

private String receipts;
private double rates;
private double allowance;

public Reimbursement() {
}

public Reimbursement(String receipts, double rates, double allowance) {
 this.receipts = receipts;
 this.rates = rates;
 this.allowance = allowance;
}

public String getReceipts() {
 return receipts;
}

public void setReceipts(String receipts) {
 this.receipts = receipts;
}

public double getRates() {
 return rates;
}

public void setRates(double rates) {
 this.rates = rates;
}

public double getAllowance() {
 return allowance;
}

public void setAllowance(double allowance) {
this.allowance = allowance;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
 return "Reimbursement{" +
        "receipts='" + receipts + '\'' +
        ", rates=" + rates +
        ", allowance=" + allowance +
        '}';
  }
}
```

JSP Adding form view:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Values form</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<form action="/adminAddServlet" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="ADD"/>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>

    <td><label>Receipts</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="receipts"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Rates</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="rates"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>Allowance</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="allowance"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label></label></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table> 
</form>
<br>
<a href="/adminListServlet">Back to Admin page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

JSP Listing view:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admin's page</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Add Values"
onclick="window.location.href='add-admin-values-form.jsp'; return false;"/>
</br>
<hr>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Receipts</th>
<th>Rate</th>
<th>Allowance</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach var="tempValue" items="${reimbursementList}" varStatus="counter">
<tr>
<td>${tempValue.receipts}</td>
<td>${tempValue.rates}</td>
<td>${tempValue.allowance}</td>
<td><a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/managerEditServlet? 
id=${counter.index}'>Edit</a></td>
<td><a href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/managerDelServlet? 
id=${counter.index}'>Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<br>
<a href="/managerListServlet">Back to list page</a>
<hr>
<br>
<a href="/HomePageServlet">Back to main page</a>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding data using Java Servlet can't return added values to JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72938238/adding-data-using-java-servlet-cant-return-added-values-to-jsp)

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. If your original question don't get answers you can try to modify the existing question. Asking the same question again does not increase the chance of an answer, rather the opposite.

Comment: I would advise you to delete one of the duplicate questions, @Martin. Also see [ask], take care to provide a _minimal_ working example with appropriate formatting. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, for your advice. I deleted duplicated question. That was my first one ever, didn't mean to be disrupting